# Execute a php script (with arguments) within another php script

Tags: php

I have two files in the same directory. I want to execute the first from the command line, which would call the second. For some reason this is not working. I'm not getting any error, and nothing is being echoed, either.

```
// test.php
<?php
    $value = 123;
    exec("php -f test1.php $value");
?>
```

and

```
// test1.php
<?php
    echo ">>>>>>>>".$argv[1]."<<<<<<<<";
?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use `include('test1.php');` and let test1.php echo `$value`?

Comment: test1.php should be executed inside a loop and work with arguments. Since I can't modify this second script, I need to find a way to execute it with arguments.

Comment: If you know the names of the variables within the second script it still could be done, but I think hek2mgl's answer would be better in this case.

Comment: Yes, I thought about including and playing with the variable names, but this is a script that isn't maintained by me, so it would be risky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not grabbing the output from that command. That's why you see nothing although the command was executed. There are several ways how to do that. This are the most common:

```
// test.php
<?php
    $value = 123;
    // will output redirect directly to stdout
    passthru("php -f test1.php $value");

    // these functions return the outpout
    echo shell_exec("php -f test1.php $value");
    echo `php -f test1.php $value`;
    echo system("php -f test1.php $value");

    // get output and return var into variables
    exec("php -f test1.php $value", $output, $return);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: `passthru()` was just my first thought how to make you see the output. Note that there are other ways how to do that which will fit better in most situations. Check my update